# Tkinter dynamic TreeView row resize

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Problem: I created a Tkinter Frame containing a ttk.TreeView widget. Each row contains text from Reddit posts. However, lenghty posts (or with plenty of newlines) are not completely visible in the row.

Question: Is it in any way possible to resize individual rows based on the content that is loaded in?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to figure out if it is possible to set a different row height for each individual row, but so far no luck. I could not find any documentation on this subject, only how to set the height of all rows (which means each row is equally high, which is not what I am looking for).

Comment: I don't think it is possible to adjust the height of just one row. You will probably need to display it by some other means like a hovering label

Comment: Alright. Unfortunate, but that's life!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to resize individual rows of a treeview.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such problem I just added right click function to treeview rows to show 'advanced view' of specific informations. When clicking on any row there is just small window shown with additional data corresponding to that row.